# Why is event undefined when using a.click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, undefined, jquery-events

I am trying to create a basic megamenu for my site but I'm having problems with the menu opening and closing on one click. This is a basic version of the HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-toggle">
        <a href="#">Toggle Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-wrap">
            <ul class="column">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="column">
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is a basic version of the JavaScript:

```
$menu = $('ul.menu');
$menu.find('li.dropdown-toggle').children('a').click(function(event) {
    var $wrap = $(this).siblings('.dropdown-wrap');
    if ($wrap.hasClass('open')) {
        closeDropdown($wrap);
    } else {
        openDropdown($wrap);
    }
    event.preventDefault().stopPropagation();
});
$('html').click(function() {
    console.log('HTML FIRED');
    if ($('.dropdown-wrap.open').length > 0) {
        closeDropdown($('.dropdown-wrap.open'));
    }
});

function closeDropdown($wrap) {
    $wrap.removeClass('open');
    console.log('Close');
}
function openDropdown($wrap) {
    $wrap.addClass('open');
    console.log('Open');
}
```

The problem is I'm getting an event is undefined error when running stopPropagation.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined

This is a jsfiddle of the error in action: http://jsfiddle.net/styphon/0go9ukky/

My questions are why is event undefined in this case? And if event is undefined why doesn't `event.preventDefault()` throw the same error? How can I get this working?

None of the search results have explained this behaviour so far and I can't understand why event is undefined.

Comment: For your code to work the `.preventDefault()` method would have to return the event object, so it would be chainable. It doesn't, so you need to write `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();` which calls these two methods of the `event` object one after another.

Comment: nevermind ... never drink and SO at the same time :D

Comment: @JaromandaX: Sage advice! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event` is defined. But `preventDefault` does not return the event. So you have to do it in two lines:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Or, in that particular case, simply `return false`. Returning `false` from a jQuery event handler tells jQuery to both prevent the default and stop propagation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot chain methods from `event` object, ex: `stopPropagation` with `preventDefault`.

Code From jQuery Source:

```
preventDefault: function () {
    var e = this.originalEvent;

    this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;

    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
},
```

As you can see that `preventDefault` does not return anything explicitly, so by default `undefined` is returned.

And you'll get error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined

To solve the issue use

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

You can also use `return false;` as alternative to the two methods.